# Sailsjs change localization

Tags: javascript, node.js, localization, sails.js

I've been using Sails.js for quite some time and was wondering if there is a way to manually change the localization from the controllers depending on the url.

Example: `http://example.com/en` will return the English version and `http://example.com/de` will return the German one.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always change the locale in a controller action by using [`req.setLocale()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/internationalization/locales#?detecting-and-or-overriding-the-desired-locale-for-a-request) or by setting the value of `req.locale`.  You can also handle this more globally by using a policy:

```
// config/routes.js

module.export.routes = {

  '/:lang/': 'MyController.index',
  '/:lang/help': 'MyController.help',
  '/:lang/contact': 'MyController.contact',
  ...etc...

}
```

---

```
// config/policies.js

module.exports.policies = {

   '*' : 'localize'

}
```

---

```
// api/policies/localize.js

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

   req.locale=req.param('lang');
   next();

};
```

Comment: No way of setting the locale without a controller?
sails.setLocale for example?
I'm using cronjob hook, and I cant access the req that way.

Comment: @StasArshanski not really sure what you mean -- can you open a new question with more details of what you're trying to do?

Comment: yea here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532581/sailsjs-req-setlocal-outside-controller

Comment: How about the API requests?

For example: We send a post request with body data:

    {
       lang: 'fr'
    }

Or set something on request headers.

Then we can return text with French language?

Answer (score 1):

Update 2020 to @sgress454's answer

> // api/policies/localize.js`

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  // This worked for testing
  // You can use req.param('lang') instead of 'in'
  req.setLocale('in');
  next();

};
```