# Sails.js - how to add locale in url

Tags: javascript, localization, sails.js

I am just started with SailsJS. I added two locales to my app. I confirmed both worked.
I would like to allow manual choice via url. Found this topic [Sailsjs change localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294790/sailsjs-change-localization) and attempted second scenario implementation - adding api/policies/localize.js file and adding `'*' : 'localize'` to config/policies.js file. BTW - this is the only line in my policies.js file (all the rest are comments).
However, when I type `http://localhost:1337/en` I receive SailsJS standard 404 page. Same goes when I tried with the second locale `http://localhost:1337/bg`.

Comment: Please check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294790/sailsjs-change-localization

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was checked and refer in my question. The thing is that when I decided to use policies approach, I am not getting expected results. Instead, I get 404.